# SQL Server : create group of N rows each and give group number for each group

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I want to create a SQL query that SELECT a `ID` column and adds an extra column to the query which is a group number as shown in the output below.

Each group consists of 3 rows and should have the `MIN(ID)` as a `GroupID` for each group. The order by should be `ASC` on the `ID` column.

```
ID   GroupNr
------------
100   100
101   100
102   100
103   103
104   103
105   103
106   106
107   106
108   106
```

I've tried solutions with `ROW_NUMBER()` and `DENSE_RANK()`. And also this query:

```
SELECT 
    *, MIN(ID) OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC ROWS 2 PRECEDING) AS Groupnr
FROM   
    Table
ORDER BY 
    ID ASC
```

Comment: use NTILE in sqlserver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `row_number()` to enumerate the rows, arithmetic to assign the group and then take the minimum of the `id`:

```
SELECT t.*, MIN(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY grp) as groupnumber       
FROM (SELECT t.*,
            ( (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) - 1) / 3) as grp
      FROM Table
     ) t
ORDER BY ID ASC;
```

It is possible to do this without a subquery, but the logic is rather messy:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (order by id) % 3 = 0
             then lag(id, 2) over (order by id)
             when row_number() over (order by id) % 3 = 2
             then lag(id, 1) over (order by id)
             else id
        end) as groupnumber
from table t
order by id;
```

Comment: Is there a need for `FLOOR` when integer arithmetic means that a decimal value cannot be returned?

Comment: @Larnu . . . No, it is superfluous with SQL Server.  I tend to put it in, because most databases do not do integer division.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the lowest value in the group, and they are always groups of 3, rather than the `NTILE` (as Saravantn suggests, which splits the data into that many even(ish) groups), you could use a couple of window functions:

```
WITH Grps AS(
    SELECT V.ID,
           (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY V.ID) -1) / 3 AS Grp
    FROM (VALUES(100),
                (101),
                (102),
                (103),
                (104),
                (105),
                (106),
                (107),
                (108))V(ID))
SELECT G.ID,
       MIN(G.ID) OVER (PARTITION BY G.Grp) AS GroupNr
FROM Grps G;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  T2.ID, T1.ID
FROM    (
            SELECT  MIN(ID) AS ID, GroupNr
            FROM
                    (
                        SELECT ID, ( Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY ID) - 1 ) / 3 + 1 AS GroupNr
                        FROM   Table
                    ) AS T1
            GROUP BY GroupNr
        ) AS T1
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT ID, ( Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY ID) - 1 ) / 3 + 1 AS GroupNr
            FROM   Table
        ) T2 ON T1.GroupNr = T2.GroupNr
```

Comment: 2 scans of the table seems a bit much for this, when it can easily be achieved with 1.